# Chamar envio de form por função

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

estou tentando enviar um form através de uma função. Segue a estrutura.

*form com id: apelido

input com id: apelido

evento keyup no input.*

```
onkeyup="$(this).check()"
```

Javascript

```js
(function($) {
        $.fn.check = function() {
            alert('a');
             $('#apelido').delay(200).submit();
        
        };
    })(jQuery);

    $("#apelido").submit(function (event) {  

        alert('s');     
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $.ajax({       
        type: "get",
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index/check',
        data: {id: '425', inputv : 'adm', nameinput: 'apelido'},
        success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
                      }
        });
    });
```

O primeiro alert é chamado, o segundo não... Já não sei mais o que fazer. Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Comment: você não pode ter mais de um objeto com o mesmo  id como o proprio nome já diz id = identificação seria impossivel identificar alguem  com duas digitais iguais, a classe pode ser igual mas o id não

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá. Aparentemente você tem dois id's iguais na mesma página, o que é inválido por especificação, ainda que se refira a tags diferentes.

Você pode mudar o id do form para algo do tipo `form-apelido` e do input para `input-apelido` e fazer as devidas alterações no selector do jquery.

### Uma sugestão:

**HTML**

```
<form id="form-apelido">
<input id="input-apelido" onkeyup="$(this).check()" />
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
(function($) {
        $.fn.check = function() {
            alert('a');
             $('#form-apelido').delay(200).submit();

        };
    })(jQuery);

    $("#form-apelido").submit(function (event) {  

        alert('s');     
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $.ajax({       
        type: "get",
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index/check',
        data: {id: '425', inputv : 'adm', nameinput: 'apelido'},
        success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
                      }
        });
    });
```

**FIDDLE com o código funcionando:** https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/971b2wgx/1/

Comment: comcordo com você

Comment: Muito bem, o problema não apenas o id repetido, eu tinha tentado colocar um form dentro de outro form, kkk, isso tudo para fazer um check no bd pra ver se o login era repetido, tentando contornar a deficiência do is_unique do codeigniter. O que eu fiz? Criei um form fantasma pra fazer o post e os dados necessários para a verificação eram colocados em variáveis globais, assim agora eu posso chamar a função de qualquer campo sem me preocupar, vou postar o código abaixo.

Answer (score 0):

Problema: Contornar a deficiência do Codeigniter na questão is_unique para update, visto que ele não verifica se o campo a ser atualizado é do mesmo usuário, impedindo assim o uso do mesmo em formulário de update.
Solução:
Form com dados do usuário obtidos do BD. Só coloquei o campo pra pesquisa por questão de clareza, mas considere vários campos como, tel, cel, cep etc.

```
<form action="algumlugarproupdate.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="pesquisa" onkeyup="$(this).check($(this).val())">
</form>
```

Formulário "Fantasma":

```
 <form id="test" method="get">
 </form>
```

Trecho JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
  var field1;
  (function($) {
  $.fn.check = function(data1) {
   //Aqui eu passo os valores da função para variáveis globais
   //Fica mais fácil de manipular fora deste escopo
   field1=data1;  
   //Aqui envio o form "fantasma" com delay de 0.2 seg       
 $('#test').delay(200).submit();        
};
})(jQuery);
 //Aqui intercepto o submit
$("#test").submit(function (event) {  
event.preventDefault(); 
$.ajax({       
type: "get",
url: 'retorno_true_false.php',
data: {login: field2},
    //pego o que foi retornado do retorno_true_false.php
    success: function (data) {
    //retiro possíveis espaços
    data.trim();
    if (data>0) {
        alert("Ops, este login já existe");
        //volto o campo pesquisado para o valor original
        $("#pesquisa").val($("#pesquisa").attr("value"));
        }
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

Acho que é isso!